# NodeJS slow startup on vagrant

Tags: node.js, http, vagrant

I'm running a windows machine and I've just setup a basic Trusty64 vagrant box.

Whenever I try to run a http app in node within vagrant (doing nothing but showing a blank webpage) it takes a few seconds to startup. This is annoying when using it with Nodemon because it means I need to wait a few seconds everytime I make a change.

If I try running the same code on my host machine the startup times will basically be instant.

Is there anything that can be done to speed this up?

Note#1 I've done most of the suggestions that jump up on google right away like turn nfs on and install guest files

Note#2 - The delay seems to happen after "var express = require('express');". Why would requiring express be slow on a VM but not on the host?

Comment: A slow start does suggest slow I/O, but according to your first note, you're already using the faster method of I/O (using NFS).

Comment: How many cores did you provide the VM? How much memory? Not necessarily relevant, but I'm wondering if you tried to provide more and if it changed anything.

Comment: @nir0s It didn't really change anything :(